# Returning the largest element from arrays in an array

Tags: ruby

I have three arrays that are combined into another array. The arrays are of different lengths, sizes, and data types. For example:

```
arr1 = [
  ["foooooo", "barrrrrr", 12121113222331144450],
  ["fooollllll", "barrrrrr", 5555555555]
]

animals = [
  ['Hector', 'Chihuahua', 7],
  ['Max', 'Chihuahua', 9]
]

people = [
  %w(Jesse\ James 123\ Homewood\ Home\ Drive San\ Francisco\ CA 510-555-1234 510-123-4567),
  %w(Thomas\ Masters 123\ Sweetwood\ Drive San\ Francisco\ CA 510-656-6589 510-123-1236)
]

friends = [
  %w(first_name last_name telephone address city state zip_code birthdate salary),
  [
    'Jessica',
    'Simpson',
    '485-123-456',
    '9210 Cheery Avenue',
    'Tyler',
    'TX',
    '12345',
    '7/6/81',
    '500'
  ],
  [
    'Alexis',
    'Tyler',
    '123-123-789',
    '9210 Simpson Avenue',
    'Chandler',
    'AZ',
    '62345',
    '8/2/72',
    '1200'
  ]
]
```

- `arr1` has six arrays with three elements in each array.
- `arr2` has five arrays with six elements in each array.
- `arr3` has nine arrays with five elements in each array.
- `arr4` has `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`.

I am trying to iterate through these three arrays and return the characters of the single longest element from each array of arrays. I want to return `arr1` has [sic] twenty chars.

```
i = 0 
while i < arr4_arrays.length
  len = arr4_arrays[i].max_by(&:length)
  len_m = len.map(&:to_s).max_by(&:length).length.to_i
  i+=1
  puts len_m
  puts "\n" 
end
```

My code does not go into the subarrays. It returns the largest number from each of the first arrays. Could someone help with this?

Comment: Can you submit some array examples?

Comment: Going by your title perhaps this is what you want `[ arr1, arr2, arr3 ].map { |ar| ar.max_by(&:length) }`

Comment: added examples to the above.

Comment: Avoid using `while`/`for` in Ruby for iteration. Instead, prefer [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) or one of the higher-order functions in [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html).

Comment: What would be the correct values?

Comment: This doesn't return the longest element from each array. I am trying to return the length of the longest element from arr1,  length of the longest element from arr2 and the length of the longest element from arr3

Comment: If `arr = [animals, people, friends]`. Does this work for you `arr.map { |subarr| subarr.map {|arr| arr.max_by(&:size) }.max_by(&:size) }`?

Comment: @SagarPandya This returns the array content itself. I am trying to return the number of chars in the longest array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the following, but I can't sure be sure of what is being asked.

```
def longest(arr)
  arr.map { |a| a.flatten.max_by { |e| e.to_s.size } }
end

longest arr1
  #=> [12121113222331144450, "fooollllll"] 
longest animals
  #=> ["Chihuahua", "Chihuahua"] 
longest people
  #=> ["123 Homewood Home Drive", "123 Sweetwood Drive"] 
longest friends
  #=> ["first_name", "9210 Cheery Avenue",
  #    "9210 Simpson Avenue"]
```

or perhaps

```
def longest(arr)
  arr.map { |a| a.flatten.map { |e| e.to_s.size }.max }
end

longest arr1
  #=> [20, 10] 
longest animals
  #=> [9, 9] 
longest people
  #=> [23, 19] 
longest friends
  #=> [10, 18, 19]
```

or maybe even

```
def longest(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) { |a,ar|
    a.flatten.max_by { |e| e.to_s.size }.
      yield_self { |e| ar << [e, e.to_s.size] } }
end

longest arr1 
  #=> [[12121113222331144450, 20],
  #    ["fooollllll", 10]]      
longest animals
  #=> [["Chihuahua", 9],
  #    ["Chihuahua", 9]] 
longest people
  #=> [["123 Homewood Home Drive", 23],
  #    ["123 Sweetwood Drive", 19]] 
longest friends
  #=> [["first_name", 10],
  #    ["9210 Cheery Avenue", 18],
  #    ["9210 Simpson Avenue", 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem use Ruby Iterators.

Using the following example:

```
arrays = [[['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','fooOOO'],
           ['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','fooIIIIIII']],
          [['baa','baa','baa','baa','baa','baaUUU'], 
           ['baa','baa','baa','baa','baa','baaAAAAAAAA']]]
```

Do the iteration like this:

```
arrays.each do |array|
  array.each do |item|
    puts item.max_by(&:length).length
  end
end
```

Output:

```
6
10
6
11
```

Comment: I am trying to get just the longest element from arr1, the longest element from arr2 and the longest elements from arr3.

Comment: @AnnLeft That contradicts your question: “print the *amount of characters* of the longest element from each array”.

Comment: This doesn't work with mixes arrays of different data types.

Comment: my apologies @AndrewMarshall - I am trying to return the length of the longest element from each array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the following, but I can't sure be sure of what is being asked.

```
def longest(arr)
  arr.map { |a| a.flatten.map(&:to_s).max_by(&:size) }
end

longest animals
  #=> ["Chihuahua", "Chihuahua"] 
longest people
  #=> ["123 Homewood Home Drive", "123 Sweetwood Drive"]
longest friends
  #=> ["first_name", "9210 Cheery Avenue",
  #    "9210 Simpson Avenue"]
```